# How to read XML from ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that would read XML and pass it to the appropriate model for processing.

How can I receive that XML that is coming in? Which datatype should I use?

Do I use `StreamReader`, `StreamContent` or `XmlDocument` or other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API uses content negotiation to automatically deserialize an incoming http request into a model class. Out of the box, this this will work with any XML, JSON, or wwww-form-urlencoded message.

```
public class ComputerController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(ComputerInfo computer)
    {
        // use computer argument
    }
}
```

---

Create a model class which maps to the properties of the XML.

```
public class ComputerInfo
{
    public string Processor { get; set; }
    public string HardDrive { get; set; }
}
```

---

This incoming XML would be deserialized to hydrate the computer parameter in the Post method.

```
<ComputerInfo>
   <Processor>AMD</Processor>
   <HardDrive>Toshiba</HardDrive>
</ComputerInfo>
```

---

If for whatever reason you want to manually read and parse the incoming xml, you can do so like this

```
string incomingText = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
XElement incomingXml = XElement.Parse(incomingText);
```

Comment: Using ReadAsStreamAsync and Load is a better option than ReadAsString and Parse.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Why is that?

Comment: Because ReadAsString may choose a different string encoding than is defined in the XML doc.

Comment: @Despertar Thanks. It works. I just have 2 more questions to ask, how do we handle attributes and nested nodes?

Comment: Attributes do not play well with the default serialization. If you were to take an object an serialize it into XML you will notice it will not create attributes (except for namespaces). You would probably need to use the last technique to manually pull attribute values `XElement.Attribute("name").Value`. As for nested nodes, those would be represented in the model as object properties.

Comment: If you had a node that contained a list of child nodes, would that simply be an object property on your model that was configured as an array? What if, for example, you had a <HardDriveList> and then many child <HardDrive>'s ?

Comment: @DougRobinson Yes something like that would work. To be sure of the formatting, try taking any kind of object and *returning* it from a controller with the content-type text/xml. See how it serializes that object to XML, that will give you a hint how it wants the XML to be formatted in a POST request.

Comment: Where do you call the the service to populate the model?

Comment: @OffTheGold The model is populated and passed into the controller method. So you receive the model as the argument (shown in the first example).

Answer (score 5):

Any incoming content can be read as a stream of bytes and then processed as required.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get() {

   var stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

   var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDocument.Load(stream);

   // Process XML document

   return new HttpResponseMessage();
}
```

Comment: "a stream of bytes" - for some reason this makes me think of a piranha-infested portion of the Orinoco.
More seriously, though, I've posted a related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994108/how-can-i-read-an-xml-file-in-a-web-api-app